# RSform- scroll screen up when posting from one form to another

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, rsform

I have a form built with RSForm pro on my website home page and when user submit that, it redirects them to a second form (booking form) and auto populate the fields selected on first form. Im wondering how I could scroll up the screen if user accessed the second form trough home page form.

I found this JS in RsForm documentations but it's for multipage form.

```
<script>
function rsfp_showPage(thePage) {
  RSFormProUtils.removeClass(thePage, 'formHidden');
  window.scrollTo(0, findPos(document.getElementById('userForm')));
}
function findPos(obj) {
  var curtop = 0;
   if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
       } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
   return [curtop];
   }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you say that when someone reaches to that second form from your homepage, he will be scrolled down - and you want to scroll him back to top? Why he would be scrolled down at first place anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in the question. I need to scroll down and focus on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in a much simpler way. In the HTML Layout of the second form, set "Auto Generate Layout" to "No". Then, add the following to the very beginning of the HTML:

```
<a name="#form-2"></a>
```

In your first form, just ensure that it redirects to the following URL: `link-to-your-second-form#form-2`